# Nested Hashes and method reuse

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, iteration, dry

I have some hashes I want to iterate, and some have nested hashes which can go 3-4 levels deep,
I am using an if statement at the moment to check to see if the value is a hash and then iterate through it again however I'm just repeating code here.

Is there a DRY way to do this using a method?

Also I want the final output to end up in a table, what's the best way to do this? That's why I had the multiple if statements originally so I could add the separate tags.

example method:

```
<% def hashTest(key, value) %>
    <% if value.is_a?(Hash) %>
        <%= key %>
            <% value.each do |key, value| %>
                <%= key %>
                <%= value %>
            <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= key %>
        <%= value %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and this is the mess of if statements I have...

```
<% parsed.each do |key, value| %>
    <% if value.is_a?(Hash) %>
        <%= key %>
        <br/>
        <% value.each do |key, value| %>
                <% if value.is_a?(Hash) %>
                    <%= key %>
                    <br/>
                    <% value.each do |key, value| %>
                            <% if value.is_a?(Hash) %>
                            <%= key %>
                            <br/>
                                <% value.each do |key, value| %>
                                    <%= key %>
                                    <%= value %>
                                    <br/>
                                <% end %>
                            <% else %>
                                <%= key %>
                                <%= value %>
                                <br/>
                            <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= key %>
                    <%= value %>
                    <br/>
                <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= key %>
        <%= value %>
        <br/>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

example input:

```
{
  "statement": {
    "generated": "2015-01-11",
    "due": "2015-01-25",
    "period": {
      "from": "2015-01-26",
      "to": "2015-02-25"
    }
  },
  "total": 136.03,
  "package": {
    "subscriptions": [
      { "type": "tv", "name": "Movies", "cost": 50.00 },
      { "type": "Phone", "name": "Landline", "cost": 5.00 },
      { "type": "broadband", "name": "Fibre", "cost": 16.40 }
    ],
    "total": 71.40
  },
  "callCharges": {
    "calls": [
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "07716393769", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 },
      { "called": "02074351359", "duration": "00:23:03", "cost": 2.13 }
    ],
    "total": 59.64
  },
  "Store": {
    "rentals": [
      { "title": "50 Shades of Grey", "cost": 4.99 }
    ],
    "purchases": [
      { "title": "That's what she said", "cost": 9.99 },
      { "title": "Broke back mountain", "cost": 9.99 }
    ],
    "total": 24.97
  }
}
```

Example output:

https://jsfiddle.net/un5ex8y1/1/

Comment: Please edit in your expected output for some sample input. We could deduce it from your mess of if statements, but we'd prefer not to have to do so. Also, not directly related to your question, but you are abusing ERb. You should not have this much code in your templates, ever. Especially not method definitions. The whole purpose of templates is to separate code from markup (see MVC and separation of concerns).

Comment: Well that's why I need the method, so I can put it in the controller and do away with the mess.

Comment: I understand the mess in the second snippet; that is what you want to do away with. It is the first snippet that I object to, which is clearly being in a view, not in a controller.

Comment: Ah, fair comment, that was just because I copied the if statement from the view just to put on here quickly, Added the example data.

Comment: So you just want keys and values of everything, separated by breaks? (You didn't give expected output. You don't need to make everything, but the first couple of lines would have been great.)

Comment: Exactly, added a conceptual example output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to display each key, each value, and each array element in a separate row,

```
def flatten_breakify(val)
  case val
  when Hash
    val.map { |k, v| "#{k}<br>#{flatten_breakify(v)}" }.join('<br>')
  when Array
    val.map(&method(:flatten_breakify)).join('<br>')
  else
    val
  end
end
```

Another, more elegant approach:

```
def flatten_all(val)
  case val
  when Hash
    val.flat_map { |k, v| [k, *flatten_all(v)] }
  when Array
    val.flat_map(&method(:flatten_all))
  else
    val
  end
end
```

then you can put in your template

```
<%= flatten_all(data).join('<br>') %>
```

in order not to mix HTML into controllers.

EDIT: I see you have added indent in your output, which has not been mentioned elsewhere. I'd recommend you use `<ul>` instead of plain `<br>` then, to achieve proper nesting, and solve the indent using CSS. You will not be able to use the second approach, since it has more structure now. The first piece of code, since it involves HTML, should not be in a controller, but in a helper (that's what helpers are for, for generating HTML from data).

Comment: This hasn't worked, it's repeated the data several times and the formatting comes out wrong, Ideally I would like it to output into a table.

Comment: The data can only be repeated if it is repeated in the data structure. And the formatting is exactly as you specified in your first post. This is exactly why I asked several times to provide the output example in your question - not the "conceptual" version, but the HTML you expect to get. I have no idea how you imagine putting this into a table (not to mention that no version of your question so far mentioned a table at all). And also, `nestedHashName` does not appear anywhere in your data.

Comment: Apologies,  I didn't expect things to become massively more complex when adding the structure to multiple iterations.

Comment: They are not. But I cannot answer a question that you did not pose - not a telepath, here. If you can adapt the answer to the question you asked, great (and it's reasonably simple to do). If you can't, then it's on you to pose a question in such a way that the answer is something you can use. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): if you want a table, why ask about `<br>`?

Comment: Also - your most recent HTML example will have no indent, which will show no indication which level you are on. Is this what you want? At this point, you'd best make a jsfiddle or Stack Overflow code snippet - a HTML mockup that you can actually see on the screen, as opposed to "conceptualising", and tweak how you want to appear visually. And using proper, real data (not necessarily all of them, but not made-up ones like "key value" and "nestedHashName").

Comment: Added a JSFiddle, sorry for confusion, not used to S.O yet.

Comment: No worries, just trying to get to the bottom of this. Where does "Period" come from? Where does the empty cell before the final "Total" come from? If you don't have some kind of logical pattern that maps between the data and the layout, you will just have to do it by hand, without cool recursive patterns.

Comment: Period is the name for the nested hash in subscriptions, The empty cell is now removed, I'll have to format that myself to create alignment.